# flask and wtf - how can I direct tag attributes for fields?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

After fiddling with wtforms, fields use widgets to actually render them to html. I wrote some custom field/widget to draw html in a way that I'd more like to. But here's a question:

suppose I want to render them with pre-defined css class or give actual details myself.

How can I achieve this? and on what phase of handling requests(at `Form` class declaration? or when setting attributes to give `Form` some `Fields`? or when I'm actually calling them in jinja2 templates) I should do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use a Jinja macro something like this:

```
{% macro field_with_errors(field) %}
    {% set css_class=kwargs.pop('class', '') %}
    {% if field.type in ('DateField', 'DateTimeField') %}
        {{ field(class='date ' + css_class, **kwargs) }}
    {% elif field.type == 'IntegerField' %}
        {{ field(class='number ' + css_class, **kwargs) }}
    {% else %}
        {{ field(class=css_class, **kwargs) }}
    {% endif %}

    {% if field.errors %}
        <ul class="errors">{% for error in field.errors %}<li>{{ error|e }}</li>{% endfor %}</ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

usage is something like:

```
{{ field_with_errors(form.foo, placeholder='bar') }}
```

This lets me avoid boilerplate, but also lets me keep the display decisions in the template space.

Comment: where should I declare the macro?

Comment: In your base template, or in a macros file which you can import using the ``{% import %}`` tag

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [rendering fields](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.3/crash_course.html#rendering-fields) section.

Alternatively, you can add attributes to be rendered in the Jinja2 (etc.) template:

```
<div class="input-prepend">
        {{ form.address(placeholder="example.com", id="address", autofocus="autofocus", required="required") }}
</div>
```

There's nothing to prevent you from using a variable for the ID value above, instead of `address`, then rendering the template with a keyword argument to populate it.

Comment: is there something between calling the field and not calling the field? what I did until now was : {{ form.address }}